# Create a mailto: hyperlink column using a Person column and another column in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

In a SharePoint calendar list, I have a Title column (single line of text) and a Contact column (person or group).

What I would like to do is create a custom field for a RSVP link.  The link would be a "mailto:" url using the Contact column's email address and the Title column's value for the subject.  For example: mailto:someone@xyz.com?subject=thetitle.  The link would be shown in Display view of the event item.

Is this possible?  How would I be able to go about doing this?

[Added Question]

Could this be done using a computed field or custom field?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Have you look at calculated fields? I think that it should be doable using the CONCATENATE function.

Comment: That was going to be my original plan.  But then I saw on http://paulgalvin.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!1CC1EDB3DAA9B8AA!208.entry that you couldn't reference a Person field in a calculated column.